# app crashes on device but not in simulator with:[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "XXXViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When running my app on the IOS simulator it just works fine, but if I run it on my device I get the next error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "XXXViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

Could this be a bug, as it is working in iOS simulator. 
Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have setup my view controller as

```
@interface XXXViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

I have created the view programmatically, so there is no xib file (and no storyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}
```

solved the issue. as I was calling it in

```
-(id)init
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
@interface XXXViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

try:

```
@interface XXXViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that gave me more errors :-) because I init with UITableViewStyleGrouped

Comment: Thank you, but I have found the error. I forgot to add this method: `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}`

Answer (score 0):

replace `UITableViewController` with `UIViewController`. Chances are that you have a UITableView and not a UITableViewController hence why you are explicitly setting up the delegate protocols in your `.h` file.

If you get other errors, please do let me know

Comment: Hi, I have already tried that, but then I get more error, for example because I have this in my code:  `self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];`